# How to get QGIS canvas in plugin window?

Tags: qgis, python, gui, qt-designer, pyqt4

I'm working on project where I need insert QGIS canvas as a widget in QGIS plugin. When user click on button it should be loaded into widget. Something like this, this is example where satellite map should be loaded in widget:
[image]

How to implement this in python code?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/171271/28714

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QT designer you need make right click on the widget and select "promote to", and write the class and header as seen in the image.

[image]

after you need compile the .ui.

In the class that loads this ui, to load some layer for example (this canvas have a objectname "canvas")

```
def __init__(self):
    """ Contructor """
    QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self)
    # Load layers
    self.airports = QgsVectorLayer(r"C:\Users\fran\Downloads\qgis_sample_data\qgis_sample_data\shapefiles\airports.shp", " airports ", "ogr")
    self.canvas.setLayers([self.airports])
    self.canvas.setExtent(self.airports.extent())
    self.canvas.refresh()
    self.canvas.waitWhileRendering()
    # Extra : set pan tool in this canvas
    self.tool = QgsMapToolPan(self.canvas)
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.tool)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: what about raster layer? Is it the same way?

Comment: Nope, you need use `QgsRasterLayer`

Comment: Is it possible to implement it in plugin that is already done.

Comment: UI file is compiled and all the logic is done. Now I only need to add canvas widget

Comment: for load raster you have this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144058/loading-raster-layer-using-pyqgis

Comment: If you have more questions, create a new question and accept this answer