# Embbeding QgsLayoutDesignerInterface in plugin widget using QtDesigner and PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

Following the example of getting the QGIS canvas in a plugin window (as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/322376/162856)), I'm trying to add the `QgsLayoutDesignerInterface` into a plugin widget.

My goal is to simply display (no edit settings needed) a map layout in a plugin widget as soon as the related map is chosen from a combobox (see image below).

*Then the layout (added to the project via the `project.layoutManager`) can wether be directly exported as a pdf file or opened and edited in the main LayoutDesigner* **(no help needed for this part since I already implemented it)**

[image]

I tried to promote the QWidget as a `QgsLayoutDesignerInterface` class to display my automated layout but I get the following error message `TypeError: qgis._gui.QgsLayoutDesignerInterface represents a C++ abstract class and cannot be instantiated`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this quote from your question:

> My goal is to simply display (no edit settings needed) a map layout in
> a plugin widget as soon as the related map is chosen from a combobox
> .

My guess is that you don't want the entire layout designer interface embedded in your widget, just the layout and associated items.

Because the `QgsLayout` class inherits from the `QGraphicsScene` base class, You can create a `QGraphicsView` object, and display a layout inside it by calling the `setScene()` method, and passing a `QgsPrintLayoutObject`.

Below is a basic example which you can adapt for your plugin (you can also run this in the Python console to test).

```py
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 1500, 800)
        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.side_panel = QWidget(self)
        self.side_panel.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.cb = QComboBox(self.side_panel)
        self.layout_names = [l.name() for l in QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()]
        self.cb.addItems(self.layout_names)
        self.cb.currentTextChanged.connect(self.show_layout)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.side_panel)
        self.layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(self.cb.currentText()).clone()
        # Create a QGraphicsView
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setMinimumSize(800, 800)
        # Call setScene(), passing a QgsPrintLayout object
        self.view.setScene(self.layout)
        # Resize layout inside the viewport (just hardcoded here)
        self.view.scale(3, 3)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.view)
        self.cb.setCurrentText(self.layout.name())
        
    def show_layout(self):
        layout_name = self.cb.currentText()
        self.layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layout_name).clone()
        self.view.setScene(self.layout)
        
        
dlg = MyDialog()
dlg.show()
```

Result:

[image]

An example with Qt Designer:

[image]

```py
from PyQt5 import uic

Dlg, QtBaseClass  = uic.loadUiType('C:\\Path\\To\\layoutsDialog.ui')

class LayoutsDialog(QDialog, Dlg):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        Dlg.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1400, 900)
        self.setWindowTitle('Display Layouts')
        
        self.layout_names = [l.name() for l in QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layouts()]
        self.layoutCB.addItems(self.layout_names)
        self.print_layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(self.layoutCB.currentText())
        self.layoutView.setScene(self.print_layout)
        self.layoutView.scale(3, 3)
        self.layoutCB.currentTextChanged.connect(self.show_layout)
        
    def show_layout(self):
        self.print_layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(self.layoutCB.currentText())
        self.layoutView.setScene(self.print_layout)
        

dlg = LayoutsDialog()
dlg.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ben ! :)

Comment: @wanderzen, no problem :-)

Comment: Sorry for the late bounty award @Ben W, I was convinced I already validated your answer ! My bad !

Comment: @wanderzen, no worries- all good! Thanks :-)